# $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} = 1$ for large numbers on calculator

Tags: limits, calculator

I've been experimenting with $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ on my calculator. Up until around $n=10^{10}$, I get approximately Euler's number. At some point after $n=10^{10}$, say, $n=10^{20}$, I just get a value of 1. Why is this? Why doesn't it continue tending towards Euler's number?

Comment: Hardware limitations.

Comment: Because the calculator cannot tell the difference between $1$ and $1 + 10^{-10}$.

Comment: That calculator was sleeping in his calculus class :).

Comment: Your brain is stronger than a calculator!

Comment: Usual high-school calculators keep up to $10$ significative digits. If that is the case, $1+10^{-11}=1$ for them.

Comment: My calculator (Casio fx-300ES Plus) for $n=10^x$ gives 2.718281828 when $x=13$. But for $x=13.000000000001$ it gives $1$. So for $n>10^{13}$, $1/n=0$ when added to another number, as far as this calculator is concerned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are discovering the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) of your calculator.  It does not store numbers with infinite precision.  There is some smallest number $\epsilon$ for which $1+\epsilon \gt 1$.  Anything smaller rounds off $1+\epsilon$ to exactly $1$.  A large section of numerical analysis is devoted to avoiding this sort of problem.  Your tests show it is somewhere between $10^{-10}$ and $10^{-20}$ and a little more experimentation can pin it down better.  A helpful, though not precisely right, way to think of it is that the calculation is done exactly, then rounded off to some number of significant figures.  Here that is between $10$ and $20$.  There may be more significant figures than are shown in the display.